# How to run a 'set' event-listener after the value has been set with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, events, sqlalchemy, listener

I have an event-listener in an sqlalchemy-project, which i want to run after the target and one other value have been saved.

```
@event.listens_for(Component.name, 'set')
def do_things(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    print(target.someOtherValue)
```

now target.someOtherValue only sometimes holds the new value(indicating a timing issue?).

How can I make sure to always run the function after the new values are saved?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem but resolved it with the 'before_update' event. Hope it works for you too.

```
@event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'before_update')
def receive_before_update(mapper, connection, target):
"listen for the 'before_update' event"

# ... (event handling logic) ...
```

NB: Make sure `not` to add `.name` on your `SomeClass` object. Use the `target.yourclassproperty` to refer to properties specific to a particular class.

Read more about [Sqlalchemy's Mapper Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html)